# Query two sheets and output on third

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two Google sheets. Sheet1 are the employees, Sheet2 are the job titles, and Sheet3 I would like to find all employees with the specified job titles.

Sheet1 (thousands of rows)
[image]

Sheet2 (there are over 100 different)
[image]

Sheet3 (expected output of Sheet1 using terms from Sheet2)
[image]

Trying to figure it out and so far no luck trying something like
`=query('Sheet1'!1:100000, "Select \* Where LOWER(F) = LOWER('Sheet2!'2:300)")`

[Demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15bWJTKmIKh1AEZERb_y3Jnwn0g_5EnpBoq54G46rMKA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you means that you want to output only Employee data with Job Tiltles in the list of Sheet 2, right?

Comment: @Ping Sheet1 has the data, Sheet2 has the search queries. Query Sheet1 using Sheet2 and display on Sheet3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: result]

try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({$A$1:$C,XLOOKUP($B:$B,sheet2!$A$2:$A$8,sheet2!$A$2:$A$8,"")},
"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col4 IS NOT NULL",1
))
```

You can always pre-process the data range of a query.

Comment: This would only work within the same sheet but I am trying to use data from Sheet2 to Query Sheet1 then display the results on Sheet3

Comment: ... there is no difference, you can name the reference range to whatever you like. I think you do know the basic of how excel and spreadsheet reference range works, right? I put the result in the same page is because it is easier to compare with the original data.

Comment: This is as simple as giving the reference range a sheet name. ```=ArrayFormula(QUERY({sheet1!$A$1:$C,XLOOKUP(sheet1!$B:$B,sheet2!$A$2:$A$8,sheet2!$A$2:$A$8,"")},
"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col4 IS NOT NULL",1
))```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the issue that was stopping mine from working

Answer (score 1):

Try below query-

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:C,"select * where B matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,Sheet2!A2:A) & "'",1)
```

[image]

Comment: `FILTER()` with `COUNTIFS()` should also work.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But is there a limit on TEXTJOIN? My query works at =QUERY(Sheet1!A1:G17430,"select * where F matches '"& TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,Sheet2!A2:A183) &"'",1) . Have 231 rows in Sheet2

Comment: Yes. There is limit. See this post please. https://support.google.com/docs/thread/90475863/text-result-of-textjoin-is-longer-than-the-limit-of-50000-characters?hl=en

Comment: If limit exceed then we have to go with `FILTER()`.